# Connect search bar with DataTable in different pages " Laravel "

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, datatable

I can't pass the search result from one page to another page which is DataTable page in Laravel,

I have two pages:

**Home Page => there is search bar.**

**Cars Page => there is DataTable shown the data with live search.**

How can I pass the keyword that user entered from Home Page to the Cars page and find this specific key what he trying to search into DataTable.

This is my code,

```html
---

Home Page Form:
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate
    action="{{ route('cars') }}" method="get">

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('get') }}
    <input id="input" name="search"
        placeholder="SEARCH" />
    <button type="submit" class="button" id="button"><i
            class="fa fa-arrow-right"
            style="font-size: 30px !important;"></i></button>
</form>

-----

Cars Page:

  
<div class="container">
    <h1>Cars <br/></h1>
    <table id="all-table" class="table table-bordered data-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Car Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#all-table').DataTable({
            ordering: false,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "searching": true,
            url: "{{ route('cars-list') }}",
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    name: 'id'
                },
                {
                    data: 'name_en',
                    name: 'name_en'
                },
                {
                    data: 'phone',
                    name: 'phone'
                },
            ],

        });

    });
</script>


-----

Controller :

  public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Cars::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('action', function($row){
   
                           $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';
     
                            return $btn;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                     ->editColumn('name_en', function ($crew) {
                return Str::limit($crew->name_en,20);
            })
             ->editColumn('phone', function ($crew) {
                return Str::limit($crew->phone,20);
            })
                    ->make(true);
        }
      
        return view('users');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Options:

1. Process the GET-Variable with PHP

The easiest way is to insert the GET-Variable into your Blade-Template in the cars-page. That way you can inject the value of the search input-field to your javascript code.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#all-table').DataTable({
        ordering: false,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "searching": true,
        url: "{{ route('cars-list') }}",
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'id',
                name: 'id'
            },
            {
                data: 'name_en',
                name: 'name_en'
            },
            {
                data: 'phone',
                name: 'phone'
            },
        ],
        @if( isset(request()->get('search')) )
        search: {
            search: {{ request()->get('search') }}
        }
        @endif

    });

});
</script>
```

2. Process the GET-Variable with JavaScript:

Simply use URLSearchParams.

```
$(function() {

    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let searchInput = urlParams.get('search');

    $('#all-table').DataTable({
        ordering: false,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "searching": true,
        url: "{{ route('cars-list') }}",
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'id',
                name: 'id'
            },
            {
                data: 'name_en',
                name: 'name_en'
            },
            {
                data: 'phone',
                name: 'phone'
            },
        ],
        search: {
            search: searchInput
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it's not working bro. can I get value from the link and send it through ajax to the Controller?

Comment: You can also use JavaScript to read the Get-Parameter and set it als SearchInput to the DataTable. (See edited post)

Comment: It works Bro "The second process". Thank you very much, you saved my life.

Comment: Nice! I'm happy that i could help. You can "accept" my answer, so other User that have a similar problem can see what the solution was.